# Do other search engines support Google's "hash bang" syntax for crawling AJAX applications?

Tags: seo, search-engines, ajax, web-crawlers

Google has a really nice document explaining how web developers can [get Google to crawl non-AJAX versions](https://developers.google.com/webmasters/ajax-crawling/docs/specification) of their web applications to make it possible for Google to index AJAX-heavy websites.

Do any other search engines support this standard?

I'm specifically interested in the fragment `meta` tag method, not just the `#!` URL method.

Comment: Personally you should always use a graceful way of rendering the page without JS support for maximum accessibility for end users and search engines - Ajax is great but you can have best of both worlds - make your pages work with and without JS.

Comment: Yeah, I'd normally prefer to do it that way also. The reason I'm asking this question is that I'm considering using [AngularJS](http://angularjs.org/) in my application, and that framework doesn't seem to play nice with search engines.

Answer (score 2):

As of 2018, Google [no longer supports special crawling for hash bang AJAX](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/ajax-crawling/docs/getting-started).

I would choose to use push state rather than hash bang AJAX URLs now.  [Google's Matt Cutts just said this about push state](http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_embedded&v=yiAF9VdvRPw):

> A correcly implemented site that uses push state typically doesn't need any extra support enabled for us to crawl it.

It should be much easier for other crawlers that might not support hash bang to deal with a push state site.

---

According to a web page that no longer exists, Bing does now support hash bang crawling.  I haven't been able to find information about the meta fragment support for either Bing or Yahoo.  My guess is that if they did support it at some point, they have also stopped supporting it.

Comment: He wasn't specifically asking about push state but the fragment meta tag support. FYI, your link to the Bing info is broken, but I have also heard that Bing now supports it.

Comment: There is no such thing as "correctly implemented site". Matt Cutts simply wants you to serve the first page rendered server-side which is awkward to implement in most full ajax apps but easy to read by google.

Answer (score 1):

Simple answer, yes, Bing and DuckDuckGo support this.

[This article](http://ajax.rswebanalytics.com/seo-for-ajax/#!searchbot_differences_for_indexing_ajax_content) suggests bing does support it. The site [imelda-immobilien.de](http://www.imelda-immobilien.de/) has no "static" pages, they're all ajax driven. A search on [Bing](https://www.bing.com/search?q=imelda%20immobilien%20site%3Awww.imelda-immobilien.de&qs=n&form=QBRE&pq=imelda%20immobilien%20site%3Awww.imelda-immobilien.de) and [DuckDuckGo](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=imelda%20immobilien%20site:www.imelda-immobilien.de) shows multiple ajax urls in the results.

Yahoo is powered by bing, and so [their results](http://search.yahoo.com/search?p=imelda%20immobilien%20site%3Awww.imelda-immobilien.de) show the same.

Answer (score 1):

Now Google not supports AJAX-Crawling anymore:
https://webmasters.googleblog.com/2015/10/deprecating-our-ajax-crawling-scheme.html

And this document officially deprecated:

https://developers.google.com/search/docs/ajax-crawling/docs/getting-started

**So don't use hashbangs in URLs.**